# Hadith on being different from The People of the Book:

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation

What is the authenticity of the following narrative? Why were Muslims asked to be different from The People of The Book - is there any context to this narrative?

> حدثنا زيد بن يحيى، حدثنا عبد الله بن العلاء بن زبر، حدثني القاسم قال: سمعت أبا أمامة يقول
>
> خرج رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم على مشيخة من الأنصار بيض لحاهم فقال: يا معشر الأنصار حمروا وصفروا، وخالفوا أهل الكتاب . قال: فقلنا: يا رسول الله، إن أهل الكتاب يتسرولون ولا يأتزرون فقال رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم: تسرولوا وائتزروا وخالفوا أهل الكتاب . قال: فقلنا: يا رسول الله، إن أهل الكتاب يتخففون ولا ينتعلون. قال: فقال النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم: فتخففوا وانتعلوا وخالفوا أهل الكتاب . قال: فقلنا: يا رسول الله إن أهل الكتاب يقصون عثانينهم ويوفرون سبالهم. قال: فقال النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم: قصوا سبالكم ووفروا عثانينكم وخالفوا أهل الكتاب
>
> <sup>— [Musnad Ahmad](https://al-maktaba.org/book/13157/22712#p1)</sup>

> "According to another narrative of an incident, as reported in Musnad Ahmad ibn Hanbal, Abu Umaamah (ra) reports that once the Prophet (pbuh) came upon a group of old people of the Ansaar with beards that were completely white. He said to them: ‘O people of the Ansaar, dye your beards red or yellow and (thus) be different from the people of the Book. [Abu Umaamaah says:] I asked: ‘O Prophet the people of the Book wear [clothes like] pants and avoid wrapping the loincloth, [what should we do?]’. The Prophet (pbuh) said: ‘You should wear [clothes like] pants as well as wrap the loincloth and [thus] be different from the people of the Book’. I asked: ‘O Prophet, the people of the Book walk bare feet and avoid wearing shoes, [what should we do?]’. The Prophet (pbuh) said: You should walk bare foot as well as wear shoes, and [thus] be different from the people of the Book’. Then we asked: ‘O Prophet, the people of the Book keep their beards closely trimmed and let their moustaches grow long, [what should we do?]’. The Prophet said: You should trim your moustaches and let your beards grow and [thus] be different from the people of the Book’."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The isnad is Sahih or Hassan:

> رواه أحمد، والطبراني، ورجال أحمد رجال الصحيح خلا القاسم، وهو ثقة، وفيه كلام لا يضر
>
> <sup>— [Haythami](https://al-maktaba.org/book/33855/1440#p11)</sup>
>
> ولأحمد بسند حسن عن أبي أمامة
>
> <sup>—[Ibn Hajar](https://al-maktaba.org/book/1673/5990#p4)</sup>
>
> إسناده صحيح. زيد بن يحيى: هو ابن عبيد الخزاعي، والقاسم: هوابن عبد الرحمن الدمشقي
>
> <sup>—[Arnaa’oot](https://al-maktaba.org/book/25794/18472#p2)</sup>
>
> قلت: وهذا إسناد حسن
>
> <sup>—[Al-Albani](https://al-maktaba.org/book/9442/1946#p4)</sup>

Corroboration of parts of the hadith may be found in Bukhari and Muslim, such as:

> إن اليهود والنصارى لا يصبغون ، فخالفوهم
>
> The Jews and Christians do not dye their hair so you should do the opposite of what they do
>
> <sup>— [Sahih Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/77/116)</sup>

> جزوا الشوارب وأرخوا اللحى، خالفوا المجوس
>
> Trim the moustache and let the beard grow, differ from the Zoroastrians
>
> <sup>— [Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/2/70)</sup>

The hadith comes under prohibition of imitation of the Kuffar, in their characteristics or in what they have innovated.